# Are perfect intervals in the outer voices approached by similar motion acceptable within the same harmony?

Tags: voice-leading

[image]

Here is a V6 to V with 5ths in the outer voices approached by leap in both the voices. Is this ok so long as it is in the same harmony?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the position change in the F chord ... rules of voice leading are referring to the chord changing concerning chord progressions and not the change of inversions. Thus the answer is yes, they are acceptable.